# How do I print to the OS's default printer in Python 3 (cross platform)?

Tags: python, printing, python-3.x

I have a Python 3 script that is going to be doing some regex substitution on some Rich Text Files (`rtf`) and I would like to be able to print out a whole directory's files on Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Is there a way to print to the OS's default printer so that it works in all platforms?

Comment: PyQt is cross-platform, and might be able to print, although I've never used it myself, so don't know if you could do it without setting up a GUI.

Comment: PyQt looks good, but I am wanting something that iss free to use for commercial development.  PyQt is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no cross-platform way. On Linux and OS X you can invoke [`lpr(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lpr.1.html) via [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) and CUPS will handle the document conversion as best as possible, but Windows is [trickier](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html).

Comment: So, I suppose I will have to detect the OS first and then call a section of code to deal with which one it is?

Comment: Or just import modules called "winprint" or "posixprint" as "print" depending.

Comment: Well, not "print", but you get the picture.

Comment: You could always export to HTML, launch a web browser and print from there. It would be cross-platform, but one more step for the user.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams sir will PyQt QPrinter wont work on all three platforms?

Answer (score -1):

With the OS module you can print files in Windows  or higher.

Comment: Looks like a comment