# Send an image to be printed to default printer...python

Tags: python, image, printing

So, currently I am creating an application that when you press a button on the GUI it needs to send the current image to the printer. It is running on windows. I have looking all around the standard library and for third party applications that will help me do this.

Does anyone know of something that could help me with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: See [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316368/how-do-i-print-to-the-oss-default-printer-in-python-3-cross-platform).

Comment: Which GUI toolkit are you using?  Eg TK/QT/wxWindows or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this link: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html

And use it to print a bitmap file that you have saved to disk. jpg and png won't work for some reason - probably because they need to be converted to a printer-friendly format.

I don't know much about this stuff, but printing a bitmap with tim golden's code definitely works for me.