# Print to standard printer from Python?

Tags: python, printing, cpython

Is there a reasonably standard and cross platform way to print text (or even PS/PDF) to the system defined printer?

Assuming [CPython](http://www.python.org/) here, not something clever like using Jython and the [Java printing API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html).

Comment: Assuming Java printing can do this another "clever" solution is JPype(a way to get cpython and the jvm to communicate/run code on each other)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no standard way to print using Python on all platforms. So you'll need to write your own wrapper function to print.

You need to [detect the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/python-what-os-am-i-running-on) your program is running on, then:

For Linux -

```
import subprocess
lpr =  subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/lpr", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
lpr.stdin.write(your_data_here)
```

For Windows: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html

More resources:

[Print PDF document with python's win32print module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462842/print-pdf-document-with-pythons-win32print-module)

[How do I print to the OS's default printer in Python 3 (cross platform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316368/how-do-i-print-to-the-oss-default-printer-in-python-3-cross-platform)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I used your answer in conjunction with @user3444876 's answer.

Answer (score 58):

This only works on Windows.

You can do the following:

```
import os

os.startfile("C:/Users/TestFile.txt", "print")
```

This will start the file, in its default opener, with the verb 'print', which will print to your default printer.Only requires the `os` module which comes with the standard library

Comment: according to https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile this only works on windows

Comment: Do you know of any way to customize the printing to print in landscape mode?

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I used your answer in conjunction with @AnujGupta 's  answer.

Comment: The Linux or Mac option is using the same OS module:

import os
os.system("lpr -P printer_name file_name.txt")

Where "printer_name" represents the name of the printer and "file_name.txt" is the name of the file that will be printed.

Comment: This works fine for text files, but does not work with images. How can we print a jpg image with this method?

Answer (score 9):

To print to any printer on the network you can send a PJL/PCL print job directly to a network printer on port 9100.

Please have a look at the below link that should give a good start:

http://frank.zinepal.com/printing-directly-to-a-network-printer

Also, If there is a way to call Windows cmd you can use FTP put to print your page on 9100.  Below link should give you details, I have used this method for HP printers but I believe it will work for other printers.

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=bpj06165

Answer (score 5):

You can try the wxPython library. It's a cross platform UI library.

Here you can find the printing tutorial:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160619163747/http://wiki.wxpython.org/Printing

Comment: This is very promising!  I don't work with python + printing any more, but if printing demonstrably works cross platform with wxpython, I would accept this answer.

Comment: I apologize @Admdebian,  I know you posted this 7 years ago but today I accidentally downvoted your answer (thick fingers). If you make an edit, I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I find this to be the superior solution, at least when dealing with web applications. The idea is this: convert the HTML page to a PDF document and send that to a printer via [`gsprint`](http://www.ghostgum.com.au/software/gsview.htm).

Even though `gsprint` is no longer in development, it works really, really well. You can choose the printer and the page orientation and size among several other options.

I convert the web page to PDF using Puppeteer, Chrome's headless browser. But you need to pass in the session cookie to maintain credentials.

Comment: I would love this, but it isn't cross-platform :(

Comment: Well, you could use the CUPS system in Linux.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421341/print-pdf-from-command-line-in-linux-similar-to-enscript-2lr

Comment: If I remember correctly, if you want to use this commercially, you'll need a commercial license, which is not free. Not a problem I suppose if you are a big business, but might be annoying for a small company, like mine.

Comment: @ShanerM13, I just looked this up. It uses the [Aladdin Free Public License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aladdin_Free_Public_License), which means it's basically free for small businesses that are using it in-house.