# standard file pointer for printing file contents on printer

Tags: python, printing

How can we print file contents on printer in python?Is there ,something like C's `stdprn` in python?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  char ch;
  fp=fopen("poem.txt","r");
  while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
      fputc(ch,stdprn);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: From here [How do you write to the printer ?](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-January/518851.html): A printer is nothing Python has or controls, it is  a standard thing for a computer system, so details about your computing environment are necessary in order to give you good advice.

Comment: C doesn't have `stdprn` either; it's a nonstandard extension from the days of MS-DOS.

Comment: Googled it. I don't think Python has anything built-in for interacting with printers; the simplest example I found delegated to the `lpr` program to do the job.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print to standard printer from Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python)