# How to physically print something out with python?

Tags: python, printing

I was wondering if it is possible to print out a physical document out of a printer with python. Wherever I look in google it talks about printing out something in the actual code.
Any Ideas?
Basically I want python to log all this data and then once a day print it out. 
The os I am using is Linux.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'physical document'? Do you mean *print* by means of a printer (e.g. inkjet)?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python

Comment: @UliKöhler I will make an edit, I mean with a printer.

Comment: This is OS dependent so you need to add more

Comment: Try PyWin32 package [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/02/14/python-windows-and-printers/) for accessing printers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to figure out how to print a document to the printer using the command line, e.g. using the lpr command. Then, you can use os.system to call the print command from your script:

```
import os
os.system('lpr <here you need to find out about the arguments>')
```