# how do i get python to print an invoice

Tags: python

parts list array

```
a =list(["CPU,$150.00","RAM ,$120.00","DVD drive $89.00","Hard Disk Drive,$189.99"])
for letter in a:
    print(letter)
```

this is my parts list I am trying to figure out how to get it to print to a printer any tips

Comment: I need to have the output print to a printer thank you

Comment: Have you checked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python)

Comment: thanks for the link i will see what i can do thank you again.

Comment: `letter`?  An invoice printed in what format?  As it stands, this question is unclear and sounds too broad.

Comment: Well, first you write an invoice formatting program, then a printer adapter making calls to your os print drivers...

Answer (score 1):

From the python windows [print tutorial:](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html)

```
import win32api
import win32print

def parts_list():
   a = ["CPU,$150.00","RAM ,$120.00","DVD drive $89.00","Hard Disk Drive,$189.99"]
   with open('printfile.txt', 'w') as f:
        for line in a:
            f.write(line)
   print_windows('printfile.txt')

def print_windows(filename):
    win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", filename, '/d:"%s"' % winn32print.GetDefaultPrinter (),".",  0)

def main():
    parts_list()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```