# Command printing with python xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

Is it possible to command printing a sheet through xlwings ?
I have look to xlwings api and do not find any doc on it ...

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Workbook(fxls)
```

how to print (on a printer) the working sheet ?

Comment: You could export it to a dataframe and then print it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python

Answer (score 3):

with last xlwings:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book(fxls)
wb.api.PrintOut()
```

xlwings is just a nice wrapper around pywin32