# How print to printer with Popen and GUI tkinter

Tags: python, printing, tkinter

I use code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python) for printing to thermal EPSON TM-T82 printer but when I modified it with `tkinter` and `mainloop()` python not direcly printout my data until I close my layout GUI. I want this script can print out my data without I close layout GUI.

This is my code:

```
import subprocess
from Tkinter import *

class tes_print:
   def __init__(self):
       self.printData()

   def printData(self):
       data = " MY TEXT "
       lpr = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/lpr", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
       lpr.stdin.write(data)

root = Tk()
app2 = tes_print()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `shell=True` is not doing anything useful there.  You don't need a shell to run a single command (though you'll need to put `lpr` in a list: `subprocess.Popen(['lpr'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: Your code does not call `printData`, I would not expect it to write anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing buffering.  The `write` will write to a buffer which is not actually passed on to `lpr` until it fills up or you explicitly flush it.

Running `lpr.communicate()` will flush it and allow `lpr` to run to completion.

```
lpr = subprocess.Popen(['lpr'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = lpr.communicate(input=data)
```