# How do I send or print the text of a tkinter's Text widget to a printer?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, printing

I am currently building a tkinter text editing application with python. I'd love to have a function that enables text to be printed out on paper like one will do one Microsoftword and other text editors, if a printer is connected, but I do not know how to go about solving this.

Comment: You could research for some things first. Also your problem is not summared in the title. It's not clear from your question if you want to create a button or a function to print a file.

Comment: Thankyou Jakub.I think is a function I want to create

Comment: Take a look at here http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html

Comment: I have edited your question. Honestly, it was not clear what you wanted to print. Please, re-edit the question if my changes do not reflect your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your problem:

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python/12725233#12725233) should work.

So create a function with a variable to store your text in (or read from a file and then pass it as a variable) and just call your function with a simple button:

```
def to_printer(text):
    import subprocess
    lpr =  subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/lpr", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    lpr.stdin.write(text)

print_button = tk.Button(text="print", command=to_printer)
print_button.pack()
```

Comment: Thankyou Simon for your answer. I have tried this but nothing happens please can you tell  me how to solve this

Comment: @FredRawllings I think this was a mistake my end. I updated my code.  If this still does not work do you get any errors?, does the function actually execute.  I need more information (I don't know your code)...

Comment: Thankyou simon your answer update works. But now the problem I have is saving the text to a variable.I first converted it to bytes, I give a print command but the printer prints nothing.

Comment: @FredRawllings Do you get any errors?  Is it in printer queue?

Comment: No it is not. What I mean it the paper gets into the printer and then gets out with no text printed on it

Comment: Hmm odd.  Is the text is actually stored in the variable before printing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169787/discussion-between-fred-rawllings-and-simon).

Comment: Thank you simon after some little research I got it to work. Your help was really awesome

Comment: Sorry Simon I taught I got the answer but I did not. This worked just once but refused to work the next time i run it here is my code

Comment: def to_printer():
    lpr = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/lpr", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    lpr.stdin.write(text2)

to_printer()

Comment: @FredRawllings  Please see in [Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169787/discussion-between-fred-rawllings-and-simon)

Comment: text = "Hello world".encode()