# How to print file from KIVY desktop app

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I have searched through many online articles trying to figure out how to print contents from kivy with Laser  Jet printer but no luck. Any useful info on this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: what is *print contents from kivy*?

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python. The fact the GUI is Kivy is irrelevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print to standard printer from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python)