# Is there any good python Module available for Printer support

Tags: python, printing

i am currently using **Win32print** module but its documentation is a mess so i want to know is there any other python module available for printer support
or can anyone point me to a good win32print support resource

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of what exactly you wish to solve or achieve with a printer module.
These links might be helpful:
https://smallbusiness.chron.com/sending-things-printer-python-58655.html

[Print to standard printer from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python)

Also check this library out if it satisfies your purpose: https://pypi.org/project/python-printer-escpos/

Comment: i am trying to print pdf with custom page sizes and sum other custom settings. I saw on how to do it on stackoverflow by combining win32print and win32api  but for some reason i am not able to change page size and this [python-printer-escpos](https://pypi.org/project/python-printer-escpos/) is only for escpos printers am i right