# Print the table from admin page django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am new to django and web development, I want to ask is there a way to print the table in the admin page onto paper?

Comment: `onto paper?`, can you be more specify? you mean print it to csv file or connect with the the browser print function?

Comment: @LinhNguyen connect to browser print function

Comment: take a look at this SO question because printer driver on python is based on different operating system https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python

Comment: what if I want to print it to a csv file?

Comment: django documents have a section dedicated for printing to csv https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/outputting-csv/