# Is There a way to print pictures With a printer using python?

Tags: python, image, printing, printers

I Saw there's an option to use the OS library, but how do i print pictures with it? For example, .png files?
***I don't want to see the image, I want to print it with a printer using Python***

`import os`

`os.startfile("C:/Users/gilke/Downloads/File1.txt", "print")`

Comment: print where? You can use opencv for image work, they allow to open and save images to files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print to standard printer from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python)? If not, could you elaborate on what you have tried, and why it didn't work?

Comment: Print with a printer

Comment: That's the exact question I went before I wrote mine, someone answered on how to print text, I meant pictures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This will only work on windows (10 or 11):**

You can do the following:

```
import os

os.startfile("C:/Users/TestFile.txt", "print")
```

This will start the file, in its default opener, with the verb 'print', which will print to your default printer. Only requires the `os` module which comes with the standard library

Answer (score -4):

first thing first type `pip install Pillow` in your terminal and hit enter
then

```
from PIL import Image
myImage=Image.open("Your Image here");
myImage.show()
```

as simple as uploading question on stackOverflow

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).