# How can I print all files within a folder?

Tags: python, windows, printing

I want to print a file first, before printing everything within a folder. I know how to import the file just to look at it.
To be more specific I am trying to print the file to my printer which is connected through Wi-Fi.

What I am asking:

1. What code is needed to print (hard copy to printer) 1 file?
2. What code is needed to print all files within a folder (hard copies to printer)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python)? It appears to be as easy as

   ```py
   import os

   os.startfile("C:/Users/TestFile.txt", "print")
   ```

   Since I'm not on a Windows system, I can't test it, but the internet seems to agree.
2. Once you know how to print one, printing many should not be any harder than iterating over the contents of the directory and filtering for files. For example, since you already have `os` imported, lets itearete over `"C:/Users/data"`, assuming that's where you keep all your files to be printed:

   ```py
   base_dir = "C:/Users/data"
   for file in os.listdir(base_dir):
     file_name = os.path.join(base_dir, file)
     if os.path.isfile(file):
       os.startfile(file, "print")
   ```

   You can also try using [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), but for such a simple use case the advantages of it over `os` are not that big.

Comment: Ok so I tried putting in this.                                                  Import os                                                                          os.startfile("C:/Users/16467/Desktop/Courseera/IBM DAta Analyst Professional Cert/Python Project For Data Science Notes/HTML Anchor Tag element.pdf" , "print") it gave me an error   saying this down below:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    os.startfile("C:/Users/16467/Desktop/Courseera/IBM DAta Analyst Professional Cert/Python Project For Data Science Notes/HTML Anchor Tag element.pdf" , "print")
OSError: [WinError 1155] No application is associated with the specified file for this operation: 'C:/Users/16467/Desktop/Courseera/IBM DAta Analyst Professional Cert/Python Project For Data Science Notes/HTML Anchor Tag element.pdf'

Comment: Alright I downloaded Adobe Acrobat DC considering it's application to look at pdfs. I didn't have it before which was making it not work. Now that I have it, it printed 1. Now I will try to print all contents within the folder.

Comment: I am confused on what you mean by (base_dir) can you elaborate on what that is.

Comment: That's just the name I gave to the variable that stores the name of the directory with all your files, should have made taht clearer. Edited!