# How to add print and sort to my contact python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, printing

```
import os
contact = {}

def display_contact():
  print("Name\t\tContact Number")
  for key in contact:
    print("{}\t\t{}".format(key,contact.get(key)))


  
while True:
  choice = int(input(" 1.Add new contact \n 2. Search contact \n 3. Display contact\n 4. Edit contact \n 5. Delete contact \n 6. Sort List \n 7. Print \n 8. Exit \n Enter "))
  if choice == 1:
    name = input("Enter the contact name ")
    phone = input("Enter number")
    contact[name] = phone
    
  elif choice == 2:
    search_name = input("Enter contact name ")
    if search_name in contact:
      print(search_name, "'s contact number is ", contact[search_name])
    else: 
      print("Name is not found in contact book")
      
  elif choice == 3:
    if not contact:
      print("Empty Phonebook")
    else: 
      display_contact()
      
  elif choice == 4:
    edit_contact = input("Enter the contact to be edited ")
    if edit_contact in contact:
      phone = input("Enter numer")
      contact[edit_contact]=phone
      print("Contact Updated")
      display_contact()
    else:
      print("Name is not found in contact book")
      
  elif choice == 5:
    del_contact = input("Enter the contact to be deleted ")
    if del_contact in contact:
      confirm = input("Do you want to delete this contact Yes or No? ")
      if confirm == 'Yes' or confirm == 'yes':
        contact.pop(del_contact)
      display_contact
    else:
      print("Name is not found in phone book")
  else:
    break
```

`

I have this but don't know where to if this is the right code to use or where to place it. I need help to sort the contact list by alphabet and add the print code, to print like to a printer. Any help? Thanks

```
  strs = ['aa', 'BB', 'zz', 'CC']
  print(sorted(strs))  ## ['BB', 'CC', 'aa', 'zz'] (case sensitive)
  print(sorted(strs, reverse=True))   ## ['zz', 'aa', 'CC', 'BB']
```

I am not to good at coding and any help with be great, with the sorting and printing to a print will be great. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hey, how do you want to sort the list, and what do you mean by print code?

Comment: Also do you want case sensitive sorting or not?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes to print the code to like a printer. And sort by A-Z. I am not good at all and need help with these 2 parts. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write display_contact() like this.

```
def display_contact():
    for name, number in sorted((k,v) for k, v in contact.items()):
        print(f'Name={name}, number={number}')
```

You may want to pass a *key* parameter to *sorted()* depending on the sort order required.

Note that the function name is a misnomer because it prints **all** contacts

Comment: Thanks you for this, since I am new to programing this help me.  One more ask from you good person, how would I get to give the option to give the user the choose to print it to like a printer. What would I need? Tried to google but just finding how to print to the screen. Any help thanks.

Comment: @NASAAndr3w07 The way you print to a physical printer will depend on your platform. There's an interesting discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python