# Passing a Text file to a printer with Python

Tags: python, printing, tkinter

How would you pass a text file to a local printer using python and tkinter? IDLE pulls up the command prompt and runs notepad. is there any other way to do it? if not how would you pull up and print with notepad?

Comment: I was wondering if you could do it in basic Python. Not using CPython or Jython. I think it has something to do with the subprocess module

Comment: CPython is just the name for the most common implementation of Python, and you're almost certainly using it. So [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723818/print-to-standard-printer-from-python) is still relevant. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316368/how-do-i-print-to-the-oss-default-printer-in-python-3-cross-platform) might also be helpful.