# Thermal Receipt Printout with Python/Django?

Tags: python, django

A restaurant currently has an online ordering system built with django, they get online orders via email but would like them to be automatically printed out as they come in. Is there a way to do this using python/django? Would I need to write code specific to the make/model of the printer?

Comment: Possible dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2316368/3991696

Comment: wait I realized that focuses on home printers I am trying to figure out how to print via thermal printers that print receipts in stores. Not sure if that makes a difference? @vishwarajanand

Comment: Actually there's less merit in deleting post. Maybe you searched but with search words you didn't get the answer. Someone else, who searches by your exact words can find the answer easily now.

Comment: That depends on how the printer system is integrated. You can make the thermal printers as default printing device and then try.